# Linux: Print specific character range in each line

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, characters, range

What is the most straightforward way, using Linux command line utilities, to print a specific range of characters for each line read on stdin?

For example, for this input file:

```
1234567890
0987654321
```

It should work as follows:

```
> cat input_file | foo 3-6
3456
8765
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answered my own question... that was much easier than I thought:

```
cut -c 3-6
```

Answer (score 0):

shell cut - print specific range of characters or given part from a string

#method1) using bash

```
 str=2020-08-08T07:40:00.000Z
 echo ${str:11:8}
```

#method2) using cut

```
 str=2020-08-08T07:40:00.000Z
 cut -c12-19 <<< $str
```

#method3) when working with awk

```
 str=2020-08-08T07:40:00.000Z
 awk '{time=gensub(/.{11}(.{8}).*/,"\\1","g",$1); print time}' <<< $str
```